# Select an ID if it's a number?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to select a list item from an aspx file from a .cs file to make the `<li>` visible. The ID for the `<li>` are numbers.

The reason why they are numbers is because this page is a custom view editor for the website, it is updating a database and then loads the correct view for the user. I need to hide some items for certain users on this page.

Snippet from aspx page:

```
<div  id="connectedSortableLists">
<ul  id="unselected"  class="connectedSortable">
<li class="ui-state-highlight" id="0">Log #</li>
<li class="ui-state-highlight" id="19">Log date</li>
</ul>
</div
```

I've tried adding in `runat="server"` to various places however had no luck. 
Is there a way to select like for a grid-view like : `grdv_dummy.Columns[29].Visible = false;` ?

I want to select the `li` by an ID to set the visibility to false to do it server side based on user. When the new custom view is saved, database will be updated with the id number. When I try with `id="item"` the desired page tries to load I get the error `Input string was not in a correct format`; due to the database having an entry of 'item'.

I feel as though i'm overlooking something although more likely completely wrong.

Thank you for your time

Comment: So you want to select an `li` by ID and set the visibility to false - and do it server-side? And you select these elements based on the fact their ID is numeric only?

Comment: Not sure what are you asking. Can you show a code to sample to see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: you need runat=server.

Comment: just curious, is DropDownList not an option for your list?

Comment: @Rahul I have edited my question, see JayMee comment. That is what i was hoping to find out the code for it.

Comment: @DanielA.White I have tried that but cannot select an integer in my .cs page

Comment: you can't set a server id to integer

Comment: why dont you invoke javascript function from server side? you can pass a parameter to javascript funciton which willl be ID...and do GetElemntById in Client side

Comment: you can do what @Viru said or use an ASP DropDownList.. you can set ListItem values and access them from CodeBehind to set Visible=False..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a way round the problem. I know that `li` shouldn't be put in other `li` , but it worked for me.

ASPX Altered

```
<div  id="connectedSortableLists">
<ul  id="unselected"  class="connectedSortable">
<li class="ui-state-highlight" id="0">Log # </li>
<li class="ui-state-highlight" id="19">Log date</li>


 <li runat="server" id="full" visible="false">                        
 <li class="ui-state-highlight" id="32">Days Country</li>
 <li class="ui-state-highlight" id="33">Days total</li>   
 </li> 
</ul>
</div
```

.CS Page

```
 full.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You will definitely need `runat=server` on your `li` elements (or `ul` element). Then you need to add letters to your ids - you can't have just numbers as an id. So something like "item". Then in you .cs file use something like:

```
private HtmlElement FindListItem(int id)
{
    HtmlElement listItem = this.FindControl("item" + id.ToString()) as HtmlElement;

    if (listItem != null && listItem.TagName == "li")
    {
        return listItem;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Basically FindControl() is what you need. Then you can use it like:

```
var item = FindListItem(19);

if (item != null)
{
    item.Visible = false;
}
```

Oh an depending on how you've setup your code, you'll use it either in `Page_Load` or `onPreRender`...

Comment: This is a very good answer, however when i save the custom view, database will update with 'item' and then when i try to view page with new custom view i get the error 'Input string was not in a correct format'. This is what i was getting when i tried a similar method. I will update question with more information. Again thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot directly access it in server side.However, you can call javascript function from server side which can enable\disable it.

At server side

```
string jsFunc = "DisableHtmlLi(" + iterator + ")";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "DisableHtmlLi", jsFunc, true);
```

At Client side

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function DisableHtmlLi(index) {
        var element = document.getElementById(index);
             element.visible= false;
    }
</script>
```